# Cannot install azureml-sdk on Mac M1

Tags: apple-m1, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I'm trying to install azureml-sdk on a Mac M1 with Python 3.9.15 and facing the following problems:

When I `pip install azureml-sdk`, it installs an old version (azureml==1.0.23)

If I run:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'BasicTokenAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_token'

And if I try to install the latest azureml-sdk version with

```
pip install azureml-sdk==1.48.0
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install azureml-dataset-runtime because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    azureml-dataprep 4.8.3 depends on azureml-dataprep-native<39.0.0 and >=38.0.0
    azureml-dataprep 4.8.2 depends on azureml-dataprep-native<39.0.0 and >=38.0.0
    azureml-dataprep 4.8.1 depends on azureml-dataprep-native<39.0.0 and >=38.0.0
    azureml-dataprep 4.8.0 depends on azureml-dataprep-native<39.0.0 and >=38.0.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first error you cited, this error is typically experienced when the provided login credentials for the Azure Machine Learning workspace are incorrect.

Verify the access rights for the workspace on the service principal you are using for authentication.
Make sure the configuration file you use for authentication is formatted correctly and has all the necessary elements.
Use the newly created service principal and configuration file to authenticate.

The second error is because these package versions have conflicting dependencies, typically experienced when there is a conflict between the dependencies of the installed packages.

You might attempt the following solutions to troubleshoot this problem:

Try downgrading or upgrading the conflicting packages' versions until you find one that works with the Azure Machine Learning SDK.

To avoid installing the dependencies, try installing the Azure Machine Learning SDK using the —no-deps parameter.

If the issue still exists, you can try deleting and then reinstalling every package linked to Azure Machine Learning.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `azureml-sdk` doesn't support Apple Silicon yet: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/26039

At the moment, you have two options. Either you install the sub-packages of `azureml-sdk` that you need and hope those support Apple Silicon or you use the v2 SDK. Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/26039#issuecomment-1275045774